# How to check Magento 2.0.2 soap api enabled or not?

Tags: php, magento, soap, wsdl

I recently configured Magento 2.0.2, i am facing problem with soap api. i created some account on system->integrations with api credentials. Now i can't able to connect to api. i am getting below error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://127.0.0.1/cms_framework/Magento-CE-2.0.2/soap/default?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://127.0.0.1/cms_framework/Magento-CE-2.0.2/soap/default?wsdl" in /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_work/api/application/libraries/magentoapi.php:51 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_work/api/application/libraries/magentoapi.php(51): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://127.0.0....', Array) #1 /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_work/api/application/libraries/magentoapi.php(32): magentoapi->initialize('http://127.0.0....', '8qfgiw1mbqmowe2...', 'ysjyt28dhxxxhuj...') #2 /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_work/api/system/core/Loader.php(1011): magentoapi->__construct() #3 /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_work/api/system/core/Loader.php(888): CI_Loader->_ci_init_class('magentoapi', '', NULL, NULL) #4 /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_work/api/system/core/Loader.php(138): CI_Loader->_ci_load_class('magentoapi', NULL, NULL) #5 /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_w in /var/www/html/upwork/ci_api_work/api/application/libraries/magentoapi.php on line 51
```

Still not able to view xml response from browser other than url 
http://127.0.0.1/cms_framework/Magento-CE-2.0.2/soap/default?wsdl

Can anybuddy suggest me, how to configure soap api with version 2.0.2.